# How to set value of class object argument as if its a dict using __setItem__

Tags: python, namedtuple

I have implemented a sample class PointLocation,

```
import collections as _collections

Point = _collections.namedtuple("Point", ("x", "y", "z"))

class PointLocation(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self._x = x
        self._y = y
        self._z = z
        self._location = Point(x, y, z)
        print "First Item: %s " % self._location[0]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%r, %r, %r)" % (
            self.__class__.__name__,
            self._x,
            self._y,
            self._z,
            )


    def __getitem__(self, key):
        """
            to make the object to be used in a manner similar to a tuple or list
        """
        return self._location.__getitem__(key)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key == 0:
            self._location = Point(self._location.x, value)
        else:
            self._location = Point(value, self._location.y)
```

and I am trying to set value of an argument *x* using:

`pointLocationObj[0] = 1`

but I keep getting error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/san/Desktop/testScripts/classObject_returnsList.py", line 40, in <module>
    pointLocationObj[0] = 7
  File "/usr/san/Desktop/testScripts/classObject_returnsList.py", line 32, in __setitem__
    self._location = Point(self._location.x, value)
TypeError: __new__() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `Point(self._location.x, value, self._location.z)`?

Comment: Your `Point()` class doesn't take just 2 arguments, it requires 3 (plus `cls` for the `Point.__new__()` method).

Comment: Did you mean for your `PointLocation()` class to handle a *sequence of points*? Because right now you only have the one point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Point` named tuple requires `x`, `y` and `z` arguments:

```
Point = _collections.namedtuple("Point", ("x", "y", "z"))
```

while you only provided two of those; you probably wanted to pass in `self._location.z` as well:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if key == 0:
        self._location = Point(self._location.x, value, self._location.y)
    else:
        self._location = Point(value, self._location.y, self._location.z)
```

You can also use the [`namedtuple._replace()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._replace) to replace a specific attribute (a new instance is returned):

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if key == 0:
        self._location = self._location._replace(y=value)
    else:
        self._location = self._location._replace(x=value)
```

If you wanted to use indices to refer to `x`, `y` and `z`, create a dictionary to apply as a keyword argument to `namedtuple._replace()`:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    coordinate = self._location._fields[key]   # can raise IndexError, we want to propagate that
    self._location = self._location._replace(**{coordinate: value})
```

Here I assume you meant `0` to be `x`, not `1`.

Comment: thanks you got it what I am after, but I would be updating either 0th , 1st or the 2nd argument of `PointLocation` so that would mean the answer  I am pasted below.

Comment: it raises `IndexError` but string index out of range that could be misleading the end user.

Comment: @san: then catch it and raise the same exception with a different message.

Comment: @Martijin, is their more efficient way then doing `**{'xyz'[key]: value}` ?

Comment: @san: use `self._location._fields` instead of `'xyz'` perhaps. Not more efficient performance wise, but more efficient maintaining the code.

Answer (score 0):

just by updating the below method, it worked as expected. Thanks @Martijin for opening my eyes.

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    if key == 0:
        self._location = Point(value, self._location.y, self._location.z)
    elif key == 1:
        self._location = Point(self._location.x, value, self._location.z)
    elif key == 2:
        self._location = Point(self._location.x, self._location.y, value)
    else:
        raise IndexError("%s takes %s has arguments. You are trying to update %s argument." % (
            self.__class__.__name__, 
            len(self._location), key+1)
            )
```

2nd Update:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    """ update the value of argument like a dictionary
    """
    try:
        self._location = self._location._replace(**{'xyz'[key]: value})
    except IndexError:
        raise IndexError("%s takes %s has arguments. You are trying to update %s argument." % (
            self.__class__.__name__, 
            len(self._location), key)
            )
```

Comment: Instead of asking for permission, ask for forgiveness. Replace `if` with `try`, and `else` with `except IndexError`.

Comment: make sense, wondering why would I have to have checks when I can do it without the checks...